# In Keras, How can i get 4D output from LSTM

Tags: python, keras, theano, lstm, pooling

I want to implement a model with LSTM and one pooling layer which wants 4D input. However LSTM's output is 3D. How can i implement ?

I want model

```
LSTM ( units:32, input_shape(batch_size,1,200),return_sequences:true)
LSTM ( units:32, input_shape(batch_size,1,200),return_sequences:true)  //3D output
pooling() //input_Shape(sample,row,col,channels)
dense()
```

Comment: How about `Pooling1D`?

Comment: It's output '3D tensor with shape'

Comment: Pooling1D is for 3D tensors.

Comment: What is your data shape?

Comment: my data shape  (data[0],1,data[1])  I changed 2D shape to 3D shape for LSTM...  data was (1821,20), now (1821,1,20)

Comment: If you need to apply a dense after the 2nd LSTM for regression or clasification, have you tried with `return_sequences=False` (in the 2nd LSTM)? That would be the vanilla way to combine LSTMs and dense layers. 

If this is not what you want/need, please tell us more info on what you need to do the pooling for, thanks!